# How to create inverted JTree in Java?

Tags: java, jtree

Actually I'm interested to create an inverted `JTree` in Java in such a way that root exists at top and its child nodes at the next level and so on.  As we know in case of simple `JTree` the child nodes appears expanding on the right side of the parent node but I want to implement inverted `JTree` in my project where child nodes expands downwards which gives an appearance of "TREE" type of data structure.

As this is very essential for my project so can anyone suggest me the code for the above mentioned problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'where child nodes expands downwards which gives an appearance of "TREE"' That would be closer to the appearance of a 'root'. 'can ny1 suggest me d code for the above mentioned problem...' 1) One '?' is better than 3 '.' in that series of words. 2) 'ny1' & 'd' are not real words. They do not make you seem 'cool', just 'fool'.

Answer (score 0):

Then `JTree` is not the correct choice. Perhaps, you should look into Java2D and stuff like that.